# SQL Server Import from csv file

Tags: sql-server, csv, import

I'm trying to import data from a `.csv` file into a SQL Server table.

Using the code below, I can read from the file:

```
BULK INSERT #TempTable 
FROM '\\Data\TestData\ImportList.csv' 
WITH (FIELDTERMINATOR = ',', ROWTERMINATOR ='\n', FIRSTROW = 2, Lastrow = 3)
GO
```

*(I added LastRow = 3 so I was just getting a subset of the data rather than dealing with all 2000 rows)*

But I am getting multiple columns into a single column:

[image]

If I use the Import/Export wizard in SSMS, with the below settings, I see the expected results in the preview:

[image]

Can anyone give me some pointers as to how I need to update my query to perform correctly.

Here is a sample of what the CSV data looks like:
[image]

TIA.

Comment: Well - what does your `.csv` file's contents look like??

Comment: I've updated the post with a screenshot of what I have. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably need to specify `"` as `Text qualifier`.

Your fields seem to be quoted and most likely contain comma's, which are currrently splitting your fields.

Or, if it works fine using `<none>` as `Text qualifier`, try to `use FIELDQUOTE = ''` or `FIELDQUOTE = '\b'` in your query. `FIELDQUOTE` defaults to `'"'`.

It's hard to tell what's really wrong without looking at some raw csv data that includes those quotes (as seen in your first screenshot).

Comment: In the Import/Export Wizard, I havn't set a Text Qualifier so I didnt think I would need to, besides everything I have read about that is mentioning adding a format file, that seems a bit excessive just to import a .csv file

Comment: @Richard.Gale I must have misread that part of your question. See my updated answer.